# Trouble iterating through an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
salesDetails:{ "1":{
  "date":"06/22/2014",
  "amount":"45",
  "currency":"CAD",
  "productID":"23",
  "status":1},
"2":{
  "date":"06/22/2014",
  "amount":"120",
  "currency":"USD",
  "productID":"23",
  "status":1},
"3":{
  "date":"06/23/2014",
  "amount":"100",
  "currency":"USD",
  "productID":"21",
  "status":2},
"4":{
  "date":"06/23/2014",
  "amount":"250",
  "currency":"CAD",
  "productID":"25",
  "status":1},
"5":{
  "date":"06/23/2014",
  "amount":"180",
  "currency":"USD",
  "productID":"24",
  "status":1}
}
```

What i am trying to do is to get all the amount per currency of all that has status of "1" and put it in an object that should look like this:

```
perCurrency: {
 "CAD":{
  "0":"45", 
  "1":"250"},

 "USD":{
  "0":"120",
  "1":"180"}
}
```

I was able to put all the currency in an object but I'm having trouble with the amount, the last amount from the object overlaps the previous one. I keep on getting `{"CAD":{"1":"250"},"USD":{"1":"180"}}` Here's my code so far.

```
function countPerCurrency(){
  var currencyArray = new Array();
  var perCurrency = {}; 

  var totalSales = Object.size(salesDetails);

  for(var i=1; i <= totalSales; i++){
    var currency = salesDetails[i]["currency"];
    var amount = salesDetails[i]["amount"];
    var status = salesDetails[i]["status"];

    var totalCurrency = Object.size(currencyAmount[currency]);
    var currencyCtr = {};

    if(status == 1){
      if(!inArray(currency, currencyArray)){
        currencyArray.push(currency);
        currencyCtr[totalCurrency] = amount;
        perCurrency[currency] = currencyCtr;
      } else {
        var currencyAdd = {};
        currencyAdd[totalCurrency] = amount;
        perCurrency[currency] = currencyAdd;
      }
    }
  }         
}
```

I know it might seem easy, but I'm lost here.. TIA! :)

Comment: You seem to want an object (*perCurrency*), but *currencyArray* is an array. What do you actually want?

Comment: thats because your key name is same

Comment: There is no method size in the Constructor of object, Instead use Object.keys(salesDetails).length

Comment: @RobG sorry if it's a bit confusing, but i just used 'currencyArray' to get all the distinct currencies in the object

Comment: @Bharath i actually used `Object.size = function(obj) {
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
  }
  return size;
 };` this function to get the size, but noted on that! I will used that instead, tnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previously accepted answer uses an array of values, whereas you asked for an object. Here's an object version:

```
var perCurrency = {};
var currencyCount = {};

Object.keys(salesDetails).forEach(function(key) {
  var obj = salesDetails[key];
  var currency;

  if (obj.status == 1) {
    currency = obj.currency;

    // If this is first for this currency, add it to objects
    if (!currencyCount[currency]) {
      currencyCount[currency] = 0;
      perCurrency[currency] = {};
    }

    // Add currency values
    perCurrency[currency][currencyCount[currency]++] = obj.amount;
  }
});
```

BTW, this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Note that *Object.keys* is ES5 so may need a polyfill for older browsers, see [*MDN:Object.keys*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for code.

Comment: This looks like the best and most elegant way to this.

Comment: I will actually use this for display purposes, so I thought it won't matter whether it's an object or array. This actually looks better, i will use this.. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    function countPerCurrency(){
          var perCurrency = {};
          var totalSales = Object.size(salesDetails);
          for(var i=1; i <= totalSales; i++){
            var currency = salesDetails[i]["currency"];
            var amount = salesDetails[i]["amount"];
            var status = salesDetails[i]["status"];

            if(status == '1'){
                if(perCurrency.hasOwnProperty(currency)){
                    // if currency already present than get currency array.
                    var currency_arr = perCurrency[currency];
                    // add new value to existing currency array.
                    currency_arr.push(amount);

                }else{
                    // if currency not present than create currency array and add first value;
                    var currency_arr = [];
                    currency_arr.push(amount);
                    // add newly created currency array to perCurrency object
                    perCurrency[currency] = currency_arr;

                }
            }
          }
          console.log(perCurrency);
    }
```

output

```
    perCurrency: {
        "CAD":["45","250"],
        "USD":["120","180"],
    }
```

I have created currency array instead of key value pair

Comment: Thanks a lot! This totally worked.. Guess i'm making it a bit more complicated.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this, i have simplified your things,

```
function countPerCurrency() {

   var perCurrency    = {}; 
       var currencyArray  = [];

   for(i in salesDetails)
   {
         if(!perCurrency.hasOwnProperty(salesDetails[i].currency) && salesDetails[i].status === "1")
               perCurrency[salesDetails[i].currency]     = [];


         if(salesDetails[i].status === "1")
         {
              currencyArray      = perCurrency[salesDetails[i].currency];
              currencyArray.push(salesDetails[i].amount);
              perCurrency[salesDetails[i].currency]     =    currencyArray;
         }   

   }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late conversation anyway try like this use `.each()`

```
var CAD = new Array();
var USD = new Array();

$.each(salesDetails, function (i, value) {

    if (value.status == 1) {

        if (value.currency == "CAD") {
            CAD.push(value.amount);

        } else if (value.currency == "USD") {
            USD.push(value.amount);

        }

    }

});
var perCurrency = {
    "CAD": CAD,
    "USD": USD
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/naxBM/)